# Snow Leopard takes a long time to connect to Windows/Samba server

Tags: networking, osx-snow-leopard, smb, delay

We run a very heterogeneous network here: There is some XP, Vista, 7, Leopard, Snow Leopard clients, and Windows 2003 (one remaining legacy app), 2008, and Linux servers. The main file server runs Ubuntu Linux and has been added to the Windows Domain and has been used for many years; SBS 2008 is the PDC (the 2003 and 2008 are on the domain also). In Leopard there were no problems at all authenticating to the file servers.

We've upgraded one of the Leopard iMacs to Snow Leopard, though the same problem occurs in a new MBP which came with the newer OS as well as a clean install on another iMac. It does not matter whether connected through wired or wireless. In the Finder when clicking on the server - whether on first boot or after it is connected - it will display "Connecting..." for up to a few minutes before either generally working (if username/password in keychain) or displaying "Connection Failed" - at which time clicking "Connect As" and typing in the username/password will take some more time and eventually work. Sometimes it will display "Connecting..." indefinitely. (I've left it as long as 15 minutes before trying something else)

Accessing shares on the the 2003 and SBS servers have the problem (so I don't think it's a Samba server issue). The Server 2008 Standard is connecting instantly at the moment. Accessing the share through an alias/stacks doesn't have this problem. Leopard and Windows clients still have no problem. I've searched Google but hasn't yielded any working result.

How do I get rid of this delay?

Comment: Found out why the Server 2008 connected instantly: if there's nothing mounted on that server it will connect instantly, but if there's a share mounted it will take its time.

Answer (score 2):

I have found in SBS 2011 anyway that when a Mac with Snow Leopard is connected and added to the domain, all shares are instantaneous. Same device not connected to the domain is experiencing the same issue as you... If you have the option to add your Mac devices to the domain you may want to give it a try...